# How to make a dictionary using two list but i want both two as a value And Key will be name and sys-id?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have two values number and sys_id. I have made seperate list for both of the values. How can save it in any other data structure like dictionary, or something else because i those list of number and sys_id are related. I am doing it in Python

Below Is the code what i have done

````
    ticket_num.append(resp['result'][idx]['number'])
    sys_id.append(resp['result'][idx]['sys_id']) ```

This is making two list one for ticket_num  and sys_id. As Ticket number and sys_id are related for example ticket_num = ['INC00012','INC00013','INC00014' ]  , 
sys_id = ['644323432sfasesdf213', '644323432dfgdfkdskrwwr', 'f283044423fdldsf09']


As this list are related like ticket_num[0] is directly link with sys_id[0] 

So can i make a dictionary that contains ticket_num, sys_id directly without creating  lists(for e.g. : {ticket_num : '...' , sys_id = '....' , ..... }
````

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` with `dict`

**Ex:**

```
ticket_num = ['INC00012','INC00013','INC00014' ] 
sys_id = ['644323432sfasesdf213', '644323432dfgdfkdskrwwr', 'f283044423fdldsf09']

print(dict(zip(ticket_num, sys_id)))
```

**Output:**

```
{'INC00012': '644323432sfasesdf213',
 'INC00013': '644323432dfgdfkdskrwwr',
 'INC00014': 'f283044423fdldsf09'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Do you actually need the lists of ticket numbers and IDs? If not that you could instead consider building the structure you need instead of the lists.

You don't say whether you want to be able to look up IDs from ticket numbers or vice versa. This solution allows you to do either:

```
idx_from_ticket = {}
ticket_from_idx = {}
# In the loop that produces the values, instead of the current appends ...
    temp = resp['result'][idx]
    idx = temp['sys_id]
    number = temp['number']
    idx_from_ticket[number] = idx
    ticket_from_idx[idx] = number
```

The two dictionaries can then be used to correlate the IDs and ticket numbers. If you want to actually do something else then I hope this code gives you enough clues.

If you do already have the lists and want to retain them then the `zip` function is your friend.

```
idx_from_ticket = dict(zip(ticket_num, sys_id))
ticket_from_idx = dict(zip(sys_id, ticket_num))
```

`zip`, when called with two argument, yields a sequence of two-element tuples, which the 
`dict` function assumes are key/value pairs.